# Trigger visual representation from google home

Tags: actions-on-google

How can I display the results from an intent in Api Ai to users phone. So basically when user ask something to the google home, the response will be audio in his google home also a visual representation in his phone.

Answer (score 0):

The best method we have at the moment would be to have your Action use something like Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a notification to the phone. There is currently no way to have a card or anything along those lines show up in the Google Assistant on the phone when you do something on Google Home's Assistant.